# my layout not align properly textview its not show above button

Tags: android

in my code i display week label  every thing is fine only weeklabel monday is not align properly seee  image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhtX2.jpg . 
How do i set textview monday properly
only i want to show textview above each button how do i do that? monday is not align properly help me please

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5,6" >

        <TableRow
            android:background="#D8D8D8"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mon"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/monday"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tue"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="17dp"
                android:text="@string/tuesday"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wed"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/wednesday"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/thur"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:text="@string/thursday"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fri"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="35dp"
                android:text="@string/friday"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/last_week"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/calender_bg"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/prevb" >
            </ImageView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e05"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
            </Button>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/next_week"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/calender_bg"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/nextb" >
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: gravity center_horizontal ?

Comment: You forgot giving gravity=center for your Monday text view.

Comment: though i am bit late, i edited your code here http://hastebin.com/rarocofucu.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of your first TableRow should be like this.

```
            <TableRow
                android:background="#D8D8D8"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp">

                <View
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mon"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Mon"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tue"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Tue"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/wed"
                    android:text="Wed"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/thur"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Tue"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fri"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Fri"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <View
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:gravity="center"` to monday

Answer (score 0):

In your `TableLayout`, remove all the padding from all the `TextView's` except Monday and Friday. Then adjust all the other `TextViews` (Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday) by giving them equal padding on left and right. Meaning if you want 20dp padding, give 10 to left, and 10 to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe get rid of the padding and add the text views for the remaining days, with empty text.